# Proguard giving me random errors

Tags: android, proguard

So, out of the blue I get this error message.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Obsolete proguard file; use -keepclasseswithmembers instead of -keepclasseswithmembernames          proguard.cfg    /Think Fast line 1  Android Lint Problem
```

And I have no idea what I did wrong. I was just about to publish this app and now I this random error. I have never messed with this file. Here is the file for the proguard:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

Please help, because I have not a single clue what is going on here.

Thanks
-Derek

Comment: Have you followed the error's instructions?

Comment: For some reason the line 

    android.library=true

was put in the properties file. Upon removing this line everything works fine. I dont know why but thanks for all your quick responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using "-keepclasseswithmembers instead of -keepclasseswithmembernames"?

There's an issue with the default template: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16384

Also clean and refresh your project, select and delete the error marker in the Problems view.

Good luck publishing your app! :)